# reset frame of relative uiimageview on hiding of another uiview ios 7

Tags: ios7, uiimageview, autolayout

[image]

Here, in above image, `UIImageView` is inside ContainerView and ScrollView.
There is another `UIView` at bottom of `UIImageView`, which will display Barcode.

What I want is, 
If Barcode will be there, `UIImageView` should be as per the ScreenShot (which is working)
but 
If no Barcode, `UIImageView` must be in Center of ContainerView and `ScrollView`.

How could I implement the same, from User Interface using `Autolayout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a fixed constraint on the imageView's bottom side to the top of the barcode view.
When the barcode is not available don't remove of hide the barcode, just set the barcode's height to 0.

Due to the fixed constraint it will also pull the imageView down.
Nte that the imageView's constraint such as a fixed height needs to be set in order for this to work, else the imageView may expand in size to accommodate the space.

A  simpler solution without auto layout is incase there is no barcode just set your imageView's centre equal to the scrollView or Container views centre.

```
  imageView.center = scrollView.center;
```